# Select and verify a value from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made this:

```
(SELECT numerocert FROM certificati) 
UNION 
(SELECT numeroarbo AS numerocert FROM cert_arbo) 
UNION 
(SELECT numeroerba AS numerocert FROM cert_erba) 
WHERE numerocert = 12
```

I want to see if the number 12 is present in these three tables, but do not understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The where Statement must be connected to call 3 tables:

```
SELECT numerocert FROM certificati WHERE numerocert = 12
UNION 
SELECT numeroarbo AS numerocert FROM cert_arbo WHERE numeroarbo = 12
UNION 
SELECT numeroerba AS numerocert FROM cert_erba WHERE numeroerba = 12
```

or you she to use a outer query:

```
select numerocert from (
  (SELECT numerocert FROM certificati) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT numeroarbo AS numerocert FROM cert_arbo) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT numeroerba AS numerocert FROM cert_erba) 
)
WHERE numerocert = 12
```

Comment: In general (for all RDBMS) won't it be safer to use the first solution? Since this won't need any improvement from the system. The second solution could return a lot of rows, and using a `UNION` a lot of check done. So this could cost a lot in memory and processing

Comment: @AxelH: Yes that's true. With the second query we'd rely on the optimizer seeing through this and making up a better execution plan. It's one way though to have to type the 12 just once (so once we want to change this to say 13, we'd have to change it in one place only, i.e. the query is less prone to errors).

Answer (score 1):

The answer why your query fails was given in another answer already. Here is another approach.

You want to know whether a value exists in one of the tables. But rather than use `EXISTS` (or `IN` for that matter), you select from all tables, glue their results and eliminate duplicates. Here is one way to select 12 if found in any of the tables (and the optimizer may apply an algorithm where it only reads on until the first match found):

```
select numerocert 
from (select 12 as numerocert) t
where numerocert in (select numerocert from certificati) 
   or numerocert in (select numeroarbo from cert_arbo) 
   or numerocert in (select numeroerba from cert_erba) 
;
```

Comment: I like this notation since this reduce the cost of the query (at least I believe it will, don't know th cost of a `in`) and limits the parameter (12) to one place.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select *
    From

    (SELECT numerocert FROM certificati 

UNION 

    SELECT numeroarbo AS numerocert FROM cert_arbo

    UNION

     SELECT numeroerba AS numerocert FROM cert_erba)  tab
    WHERE numerocert = 12
```

You need to wrap the result of unions into one table then apply query on that